# Background Video Change?

Tags: jquery, function, video, background

I am looking to have a video as my full background, but then using jquery functions, have the user be able to click anywhere on the page which changes the video.

I looked at the show and hide functions, but I am still new to this, so I'm confused and am looking for the easiest way to go about this.

Any advice on how to to that?